# Create a compact privacy policy

Tags: cookies, privacy-policy

I'm looking into the idea of using cookies for tracking purposes and have noticed that my current website hasn't got a compact privacy policy.

I've googled it and there are ways to create them but at a price.

Just wondering if there was a way to do this without paying for it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am busy with the same thing. All the free tools do not work it seems.

This post: [W3 P3P](http://www.w3.org/TR/P3P/#intro_example) seems to help, busy doing it this way now. Luckily it is basically only 2 or so xml files you need to put in the www/w3c/ folder on the webserver.

Also run this tool [P3P Validator](http://www.w3.org/P3P/validator.html) to test everything.

Also remeber to add the Compact P3P into your HTTP header.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a very detailed and high quality privacy policy, really near to a hand made one, thanks to this service called iubenda. There are both a Free and a Paid version, check it out:
http://www.iubenda.com/en

(I'm the founder ;) )

Answer (score 1):

While I love iubenda.com, I also wanted to throw out http://www.privacychoice.org/ as an good alternative as-well.

Reviews of both (and a few others) are here: http://www.applicationprivacy.org/do-tools/privacy-policy-generator/

I have used both sites and have no ties to either.