# IE 8 not creating session cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, internet-explorer-8

I have a .net web application, working fine on most of the browsers and machines but only some machines having IE 8 won't create session cookies and hence wont allow users to login. I have tried resetting browser settings to default settings, also the domain is allowed for the cookies in the browser settings - tried compatibility mode as well. Again this is happening only on certain machines. I would appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: Just found the machine is running windows 7 64 bit and have two versions of IE 8 installed i.e. IE 8 64 bit an 32 bit. All working in IE 64 bit but not in 32 bit

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am experiencing the same problem

Comment: Are there any other differences, such as browser add-ins installed? If so might be worth disabling them to rule that out

Answer (score 1):

Since it happens only on certain machines, maybe you should check the date/time in the machines where the issue is occuring. Maybe the cookie's expiration date is being affected by these configurations.

Comment: That was probably one of the first thing we checked and its all fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because I did not have a cookie privacy policy set in my META tags. You should have something like this in the header of your HTML:
`<meta http-equiv="P3P" content='CP="OTI DSP COR DEVa ADMa OUR IND ONL STA"' />`

see here: [Create a compact privacy policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337876/create-a-compact-privacy-policy)

Comment: If it is indeed the P3P issue you can also fix it "the Google way" by specifying a clearly invalid string like "CP=&quot;This is not a P3P policy!&quot;".

See also: http://www.techpolicy.com/Cranor_InternetExplorerPrivacyProtectionsBeingCircumvented-by-Google.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could be running into one of the limits imposed by the browser (max cookies, max cookies per domain, max cookie size).  You mentioned that you're specifically having problems with authentication.

Are you using Forms Authentication?  If so, are you trying to store a large amount of data in the UserData property of a FormsAuthenticationTicket?  This can cause the FormsAuthentication cookie size to go beyond the browser-imposed limit.  You don't get any clue as a developer that you ran up against one of these limits and your users don't get any warnings or errors so that they can tip you off.

Otherwise, are you setting a lot of cookies generally in your app?  Or large cookies?  Or could other applications that share the same domain as you be?  Make sure you don't mix up cookies w/session state, as session state typically only stores 1 cookie to reference state stored server-side.  If you can troubleshoot from the machine, take a look at the developer tools and see how many cookies are involved after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 is very strict with cookies. Check the server time and local machine`s time. And also check the agent string.